# Wrong color displayed after converting from HSV to RGB (python openCV)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors, hsv

I would like to select the color Lime in an image (the method I am using is described [here](https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/)).
But I want to display this color first before selecting it.
Lime is `(120,100,100)` in HSV ([source](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html)).

```
green = (120, 100, 100)
g_square = np.full((10, 10, 3), green, dtype=np.uint8) / 255.0
plt.imshow(hsv_to_rgb(g_square))
plt.show()
```

My issue is that I don't have lime displayed but rather a dark green.

[image]

Comment: Opencv follows BGR convention by default, and the `imshow` would display the images assuming `BGR` convention, so try to convert your matrix in the `BGR` format before using `imshow()`

Comment: Note that openCV uses other value ranges than the website you mentioned. openCV uses HSV - [0-179][0-255][0-255]. Read it [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)